# Lebesgue's differentiation theorem for all points

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^2(0,T)$ be such that $f(t)$ is well-defined for every $t$ (not just a.e. $t$). But I have no continuity of $f$.

We have by Lebesgue's differentiation theorem that
$$\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{1}{a}\int_{t-a}^t f(s) = f(t)$$ for **almost all $t \in [0,T]$**. Could it be the case that for my particular $f$ that this statement can be strengthened to **for all $t \in [0,T]$**?

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined? $L^2$ is a space of equivalence classes. Define $\tilde{f}(t)$ to equal $f(t)$ on $(0,T)\setminus \{T/2\}$ and $\tilde{f}(T/2) = \infty.$ Then $\tilde{f} = f$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Yes, for example this holds for all $t$ in the case that $f$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have problems with points of discontinuity. For instance, if $f(x) = \chi_{[T/2,T]}(x)$ then 
$$\int_{T/2-a}^{T/2} f(s) \, ds = 0$$ for all $0 < a < T/2$, but $f(T/2) = 1$.